# Search for specific text in log files, then merge all the contents of the log files into one file

Tags: linux, bash

I am currently running a program that docks drugs to certain proteins and gives it a grade in numbers. For one run it creates a unique directory with files: log.txt and out.pdbqt (.pdbqt files are basically 3D coordinates for the drug). I do this for thousands of drugs, so I make thousands of sub directories in one main directory. It creates a mess. I was wondering what the commands for a Linux terminal or a bash script to search for specific text ( an example of the text would be -8.* or -12.* ) in all log.txt files in all directories of the one I am in. Then any directory that contains that file with the specific text, is then copied into a new one named results. I do **not** want to merge the .pdbqt files (it can mess up the xyz coordinates). Essentially I would like for all the directories that have the text ,in the log.txt files, that I search for to be copied in one directory named results.

What I am running that is less efficient is this.

```
`#! /bin/bash

for f in drugbank/ligands_*.pdbqt; do
    b= basename $f .pdbqt
    echo Processing ligand $b
    mkdir -p $b
    ./vinaXB --config conf.txt --ligand $f --out ${b}/out.pdbqt --log ${b}/log.$
done`
```

What this does is run the program for all drugs in the sub directory /drugbank/
and creates directories in the main directory the program is in based on the title of the file of the drug. In this case ligands_*.pdbqt.

Then I use :

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec grep -il '-8.*' {} \;
```

I then manually copy and paste the given files into one folder and double check it gives me the appropriate score.

Also if you can give me a linux command that tells a program to open all files with a given name in all sub-directories that would be peachy. Let's say I already used export and changed the ./~bashrc.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right, there's is only a tiny piece missing to solve your problem:

I simulated your problem by the following command:

```
$ find . -name "*.cc" -exec grep -l 'main' {} \;
./autocorrelation.cc
./QATM/testQATM.cc
./QDockTreeView/testQDockTreeView.cc
./QFileDialog/testQFileDialog.cc
./QFontMetric/testQFontMetric.cc
./QGLWidgetHUD/testQGLWidgetHUD.cc
./QLabelImage/testQLabelImage.cc
./QPopup/testQPopup.cc
./QProcess/testQProcess.cc
./QRadioButtonRichText/testQRadioButtonRichText.cc
./QTableViewNoScroll/testQTableViewNoScroll.cc
./QWidgetKineticScroll/testQWidgetKineticScroll.cc
./test-bimap-mt.cc
./test-bimap.cc
./test-cout.cc
./test-dup-symbol.cc
./test-hex.cc
./test-longdouble.cc
./test-master-slave.cc
./test-op-plus.cc
./test-swap.cc
./testVecRef.cc
./testVSDebug.cc
```

It provides a list of paths for every file which contains a certain pattern (`main` in my case). So, what to do with this list? I feed it into a `while read` loop for further processing:

```
$ find . -name "*.cc" -exec grep -l 'main' {} \; \
> | while read FILE; do echo cp "$FILE" ./hits/ ; done
cp ./autocorrelation.cc ./hits/
cp ./QATM/testQATM.cc ./hits/
cp ./QDockTreeView/testQDockTreeView.cc ./hits/
cp ./QFileDialog/testQFileDialog.cc ./hits/
cp ./QFontMetric/testQFontMetric.cc ./hits/
cp ./QGLWidgetHUD/testQGLWidgetHUD.cc ./hits/
cp ./QLabelImage/testQLabelImage.cc ./hits/
cp ./QPopup/testQPopup.cc ./hits/
cp ./QProcess/testQProcess.cc ./hits/
cp ./QRadioButtonRichText/testQRadioButtonRichText.cc ./hits/
cp ./QTableViewNoScroll/testQTableViewNoScroll.cc ./hits/
cp ./QWidgetKineticScroll/testQWidgetKineticScroll.cc ./hits/
cp ./test-bimap-mt.cc ./hits/
cp ./test-bimap.cc ./hits/
cp ./test-cout.cc ./hits/
cp ./test-dup-symbol.cc ./hits/
cp ./test-hex.cc ./hits/
cp ./test-longdouble.cc ./hits/
cp ./test-master-slave.cc ./hits/
cp ./test-op-plus.cc ./hits/
cp ./test-swap.cc ./hits/
cp ./testVecRef.cc ./hits/
cp ./testVSDebug.cc ./hits/
```

Some notes:

1. I used `\`**ENTER** to format the command. The `>` at beginning of second line is output of bash (to notify about line continuation). You may leave all this out.
2. My actually looped command was `echo`. If I had removed it the loop has copied all the files (and had made the left free space on my SSD even smaller). I'm sure you will be able to replace `echo cp` with whatever is suitable in your case.
3. I did this on Windows 10 (64 bit), cygwin, and bash but it should work on Linux (and every other Unix-like OS) also.

After reading your question again I noticed that you ask (in the title) for merging all files into one file. I missed it somehow in the text.

However, `cat` is the command to con-*cat*-enate files. In this case, `cat` is used for output only, and the concatenation is achieved by the appending re-direction `>>` e.g.:

```
$ rm ./hits.txt ; find . -name "*.cc" -exec grep -l 'main' {} \; \
| while read FILE; do cat "$FILE" >> ./hits.txt ; done
rm: cannot remove './hits.txt': No such file or directory

$ ls -l hits.txt
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 ????? ????? 81698 Mar 18 09:19 hits.txt
```

Notes:

1. I did also a `less hits.txt` to check whether it worked. It did but I don't want to paste all the output (81698 bytes) here.
2. The error message `rm: cannot remove './hits.txt': No such file or directory` occurs only if ./hits.txt is not available. `>>` means "append". Thus, it might be important to remove previous results before collecting new. Because, I'm used to re-call command lines out of bashs history it becomes reasonable for repeated calls. (However, if `rm` fails this way it shouldn't have any bothering side effect.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'll try it out when my calculations are done!